# Please explain this Vim mapping alias(?)

Tags: vim

I've found a feature, quite a while ago actually but only now am I interested in knowing what it does. It's the following:

```
nm <space> [space]
nn [space] <NOP>

nm [space]F :VimFiler<CR>
```

What exactly is this doing? What are the advantages of using this instead of just `<space>`? Except that it seems to work as an alias, so you can change what `[space]` means and that changes all the keybinds that are used by this.

How does this work? Official documentation or something that explains it in detail how it works would be more than appreciated. :)

Comment: Not sure, however i've used this guy when mapping within vim( a while ago now to be honest)  it is pretty comprehensive: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything special about `[space]`. The first mapping makes it so that pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> is the same as having typed those characters. The second makes it so that typing `[space]` on its own doesn't do anything (`<NOP>` is special). The last makes it so that typing `[space]F` does that command. You can see that this is true by actually pressing the keys `[space]F` and seeing that it does it too. It seems kind of like a way to emulate the `<Leader>` and `<LocalLeader>` functionality, but IMO a rather poor way of doing it.

Comment: Hugh. I thought for sure it was something special. Didn't even consider this option. I won't accept your answer just yet, just in case, but if there's no other answer I'll be sure to accept yours. :)